# Reuse Cipher (prevent init)

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-ndk, cryptography

I'm trying to improve our crypto performance. We need to stream encrypted video, so we encrypt each frame (h.264 NALU, to be precise) and send it over network. We can't eventr stream PAL video on Android this way.

We are using AES (`AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding`), and we use the same key and IV for each frame in session. I know, it's not very secure, but I was not there when this was implemented and it's too late to change that. So, for each frame we call `Cipher.init()` with same parameters (key and IV) and then just call `doFinal`. Is it somehow possible to prevent this and reuse already initialized `Cipher` object?

Or is there some better algorithm for video streams than AES? We are using SpongyCastle. Is there something faster? Or should we rewrite it in NDK using OpenSSL?

Comment: Yes, Init() Cipher one time, and you can use doFinal multiple times.

Comment: This likely won't change anything on the performance side.

Comment: @ArtjomB. well, the key schedule may not have to be run. Compared to encrypting multiple frames this should indeed not make a whole lot of differences. Pitel, have you thought about parallel encryption? As for the algorithm: some stream ciphers may be faster, say ChaCha20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `init()` just once and then calling `doFinal()` repeatedly is what we did, and it improved througput by more than 50 %.

Answer (score 0):

> is there some better algorithm for video streams than AES?

It depends on how strong your cryptography should be. What is the main criteria.

> Is there something faster?

If the main criteria is the speed then look to some **stream** cipher. They are faster (designed to transfer audio/video streams) but weaker then **block** cipher AES.

Also using AES in CBC mode you can enhance decryption - it can be parallelized.